# LMERConvenienceFunctions error on back and forward fitting functions: model not a mer object

Tags: r, lme4

I tried using `bfFixefLMER_t.fnc` or `fitLMER.fnc` from the `LMERConvenienceFunctions` package. In both the cases, I get an error that "the input model is not a mer object".

I tried out the examples from http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/LMERConvenienceFunctions/html/00Index.html. I get the same errors.

For example when I run from the example

```
fitLMER.fnc(mB, backfit.on = "t", item = FALSE, 
    ran.effects = c("(FreqB | Subject)",
    "(LengthB | Subject)", "(WMC | Item)"))
```

this is the result I get.

```
Warning in fitLMER.fnc(mB, backfit.on = "t", item = FALSE, ran.effects = c("(FreqB | Subject)",  :resetting argument "method" to "t"

**backfitting fixed effects**

Warning in bfFixefLMER_t.fnc(model = model, item = item, method = method,  :factor variable with more than two levels in model terms, backfitting on t-values is not appropriate, please use function "bfFixefLMER_F.fnc" instead.

Error in bfFixefLMER_t.fnc(model = model, item = item, method = method,  : the input model is not a mer object
```

Has anyone had this experience with these functions?

There are functions that back fit fixed effects and forward fit random effects. 
Is there a way to do forward fitting of fixed effects for the `glmer` models? Or is this statistically meaningless? I am working on ecological modelling, so my understanding of advanced stats is not much, so, please, if someone can explain in layman's terms better

```
sessionInfo()
```

R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] LMERConvenienceFunctions_2.0 lme4_0.99999911-8
[3] RcppEigen_0.3.1.2.1          Rcpp_0.10.4
[5] Matrix_1.0-12                lattice_0.20-23
[7] LCFdata_1.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_3.0.1    MASS_7.3-28   minqa_1.2.1   nlme_3.1-111  rpart_4.1-2
[6] splines_3.0.1 tools_3.0.1

Comment: have you updated `lme4` to the latest, about-to-be-released version (>1.0?)  It might have broken `LMERConvenienceFunction`.  I *think* this will turn out to be a programming, not a statistical, question.  `sessionInfo()` please?

Comment: I don't have the yet-to-be-released version of lme4. Would this question be more appropriate in SO? If yes, can I move it myself or it requires a moderator to do it?

Comment: I have added the sesionInfo() and the complete lsit of warnings/errors I get when I run the example. May be it says something more where there might be a conflict.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using an (older) version of the overhauled `lme4` package that returns `merMod` objects instead of `mer` objects, and hence is not compatible with `LMERConvenienceFunctions`. I get the same error when using the soon-to-be-released version 1.0-4.

If I install the latest version from CRAN instead (0.999999-2), no errors arise. I suggest removing your current `lme4` and installing the latest from CRAN, and checking its version:

```
> detach("package:lme4",unload=TRUE)
> remove.packages("lme4")
> install.packages("lme4")
> packageVersion("lme4")
[1] ‘0.999999.2’
```

This should fix your problems. Be aware, however, that you will lose the [advantages of the new version](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/blob/master/misc/notes/release_notes.md).

Also, in the coming days the new `lme4` should appear on CRAN, breaking `LMERConvenienceFunctions` again if you update your packages. I guess, however, that the authors of `LMERConvenienceFunctions` will update their package soon to be compatible again.

Comment: Thanks. It works. I usually keep my packages updated. this one must have slipped. Noticed some more changes in the lme4 concerning the use of `$` and `@` for extracting the summary results.