# How can I run lme4 with pvals.fnc to compute p value in Mavericks

Tags: r, lme4, osx-mavericks

Everything used to work fine, but now, after i upgraded my Macbook to Mavericks, and R to 3.0.2, I also have to upgrade languageR and lme4 packages, now languageR is 1.4 and lme4 is 1.0.4.

The problem is that I always get this error:

```
  > pvals.fnc(mod1)
  the input model is not a mer object
  NULL
```

Someones suggests to use other ways to compute p value ([lme4 and languageR compatibility error: "input model is not a mer object”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19199713/lme4-and-languager-compatibility-error-input-model-is-not-a-mer-object)). But I don't only need p value, i also need other parameters that pvals.fnc can return. Someone suggests to downgrade lme4 to ‘0.999999.2’ ([LMERConvenienceFunctions error on back and forward fitting functions: model not a mer object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18791725/lmerconveniencefunctions-error-on-back-and-forward-fitting-functions-model-not)), but unfortunately I cannot install ‘0.999999.2’ on Mavericks. It shows the following errors:

```
installing *source* package ‘lme4’ ...
package ‘lme4’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
libs Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/share/make/shlib.mk:6: warning: overriding commands for target `lme4.so'
Makevars:7: warning: ignoring old commands for target `lme4.so'
llvm-gcc-4.2 -arch x86_64 -std=gnu99 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -     I/usr/local/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/Matrix/include" -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/stats/include"   -fPIC  -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c    init.c -o init.o
/bin/sh: llvm-gcc-4.2: command not found
make: *** [init.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘lme4’
removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/lme4’
restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/lme4’
Warning in install.packages :
 installation of package ‘/Users/nanli/Downloads/lme4_0.999999-2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Anyone has ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: This is not the first question on SO to report failure to compile portions of R on a Mac. I don't know the solution but did comment to the other poster that there was a major change in XCode compilers with Mavericks. `llvm-gcc-4.2` is no longer part of XCode. Personally, I'm not planning to update until I see more signs of success on the R-SIG-MAC mailing list.

Comment: (Although when I looked just now it appears that both Brian Ripley and Simon Urbanek have installed version 3.0.2 on Mavericks.)

Comment: Hi @DWin Do you know how to install llvm-gcc-4.2, I tried the command line tool with XCode 5, but it does not seem to come with llvm-gcc

Comment: I think you should be asking on an OSX Developer forum or reading R-SIG-Mac. This issue was discussed in postings today and I am not sufficiently skilled to improve upon the answers (and I have not yet updated to Mavericks.)

Comment: Can you download and install this binary version? http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/repos/bin/macosx/contrib/3.0/lme4_0.99999911-8.tgz

Comment: @BenBolker  Hi Ben, I downloaded it, but I don't know why, it still does not generate any results.

Comment: I'm afraid I need more detail than that to help.  What are the error messages?

Comment: I've also just added a binary version of lme4.0 to the lme4 repository at http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/repos/bin/macosx/contrib/3.0/ . It's not there yet (it will take up to 24 hours to update), but it's probably what you should use, i.e. `install.packages("lme4.0",repos="http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/repos")`

Comment: Thanks for adding that binary version @BenBolker! I've installed it and loaded it, and now can extract fixed effect coefficients from models generated using lmer; however, pvals.fnc and pamer.fnc aren't working for me. The former gives me `MCMC sampling is not implemented in recent versions of lme4 for models with random correlation parameters`; the latter gives me `Error in UseMethod("ranef") : 
  no applicable method for 'ranef' applied to an object of class "mer"`. The model I'm building has a fixed and random effect. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure about the latter: for the former, it's been a while since `pvals.fnc` was able to use `mcmcsamp()` on a vector-valued random effect: are you sure that particular example was working before?  Note that `pamer.fnc` is from the `LMERConvenienceFunctions` package ... have you asked the maintainer ... ??